# NServiceBus on ASP.NET 5 cannot find event meta data in unobtrusive mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nservicebus

I am trying to use NServiceBus in an ASP.NET 5 Web application.  When invoking IBus.Send(purchaseTransactionAddedEvent) where purchaseTransactionAddedEvent is of type PurchaseTransactionAddedEvent defined in another assembly called Infrastructure.Contract, I get this error:

> Message=Could not find metadata for
>   'Infrastructure.Contract.Events.PurchaseTransactionAddedEvent'. Please
>   ensure the following:
>   1. 'Infrastructure.Contract.Events.PurchaseTransactionAddedEvent' is included in initial scanning. 
>   2. 'Infrastructure.Contract.Events.PurchaseTransactionAddedEvent' implements either 'IMessage', 'IEvent' or 'ICommand' or alternatively,
>   if you don't want to implement an interface, you can use 'Unobtrusive
>   Mode'.   Source=NServiceBus.Core

I am using Unobtrusive Mode when configuring the endpoint as follows:

```
            busConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();

            // we are using In memory persistence for messages
            busConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();

            // NOTE: this is important and has to be set on publisher and subscriber endpoints.
            // We are using unobstrusive mode, so our messages/events do not have to implement IMessage, IEvent, etc
            var conventionsBuilder = busConfiguration.Conventions();
            conventionsBuilder.DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace == "Infrastructure.Contract.Events");
```

But this does not appear to be working within the new ASP.NET 5 folder arrangement.

Logging has been enabled on NServiceBus but it does not tell me what assemblies it is scanning.  Given that ASP.NET 5 no longer has a bin folder, how does one go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1):

Bus.Send is looking for commands, not events. Events are published through Bus.Publish. But you [should not send/publish events from a website](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/publishing-from-web-applications). First send a command to a handler, and let the handler publish the event. Check [this article](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/messages-events-commands) for more information.

Try this

```
var configuration = new BusConfiguration();
configuration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
configuration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(x => x.ExistingLifetimeScope(container));

ConventionsBuilder conventions = configuration.Conventions();
conventions.DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Infrastructure.Contract") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Commands"));

Bus = NServiceBus.Bus.CreateSendOnly(configuration);
```

And then send your command via Bus.Send(myCommand)

Comment: Why shouldn't a web app publish an event?

Comment: @JeffDunlop Does this answer your question?
http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/publishing-from-web-applications

The logical publisher is a very important reason.

Comment: "Should not" and "should avoid" are entirely different things; thanks for the link.

Comment: Based on the link you provided publishing from a web application only requires you to take take into consideration certain guidelines, especially with NServiceBus 5+.

Comment: Another thing, reverted to ASP.NET 5 and commands can be sent and received across two ASP.NET 5 applications.   However, events published on one cannot be received by the other.

Comment: They can, but you "should avoid" that. you can also build your own CRM, but you should "avoid that". You can even send asynchronous messages to some service and wait for a callback, all via asynchronous messaging. But again, you "should avoid" that. I'd even say to all the things mentioned here, that you "should not" do that. :) There are better alternatives.